# Why is QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable() False running as root but True as user?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

On Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome3 and X11 and Qt5.12.8 (PyQt 5.14.1)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication
qapp = QApplication([''])
print(str(QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable()))
```

shows `True` as user and `False` as root (via `sudo` as well as via `pkexec`).

1. How can I find out the reason for "`False` as root" (is there a way to enable logging for this) and
2. how can I enable system tray icons also for code running as root?

I have also tried to inject the user's X11 env vars but this does not help:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY python3 -c "from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication; qapp = QApplication(['']); print(str(QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable()))"
```

**Edit:** I think the relevant Qt5 source code is here:

[QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9e251d44a79e171f093e89b21215d7372866ef4c/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon.cpp#L350-L353)

[QSystemTrayIconPrivate::isSystemTrayAvailable_sys()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/067b53864112c084587fa9a507eb4bde3d50a6e1/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon_x11.cpp#L282-L293)

Comment: Running GUI programs as root (assuming that the current user is not root, obviously) is always discouraged, as it can create serious issues depending on how the program accesses the environment. Besides, it might even possible that the window manager itself prevents other users to add icons to the tray (by design, or might be a bug).

Comment: Yes, I agree and am totally aware of the "no root GUI" principle (e.g. enforced by native Wayland) and using polkit instead. I am maintaining a legacy software and want to fix this bug since for a huge refactoring there is not enough man power and strictly seen the root part does show only a status. In fact most of the other distros (even with Wayland on KDE plasma) do show a sys tray icon if I run as root and I want to understand how qt5 does decide this (looking into the qt5 source code I could not find a clue so far).

Comment: It doesn't directly depend on the display server but on the window manager. By default, on Linux, it works through a query to dbus, so it depends on its reply and how the wm deals with permissions. Unfortunately I don't know dbus and desktop integration enough to tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding question 1: I have found the correct logging settings and reason**

> 1. How can I find out the reason for "False as root" (is there a way to enable logging for this)?

I have to enable the logging for the logging category `qt.qpa.*`

```
pkexec env "QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.*=true" DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY python3 -c "from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication; qapp = QApplication(['']); print(str(QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable()))"
```

to get a lot of diagnostic output with this important line:

> qt.qpa.menu: StatusNotifierHost is not registered

Looking into the [source code of Qt5](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/067b53864112c084587fa9a507eb4bde3d50a6e1/src/gui/platform/unix/dbusmenu/qdbusmenuconnection.cpp#L47) I found out that `isSystemTrayAvailable()` is trying to query a user session D-Bus property at

`org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher/StatusNotifierWatcher/IsStatusNotifierHostRegistered`

which is only available when running as user but not when running as root.

This can be verified by running `qdbusviewer` as user

[image]

vs. as root (via the same `pkexec` call like in the question):

[image]

**Summary: As root the user' D-Bus session cannot be called (without further tweaks)**